# Dynamically add and remove component on button click?

Tags: jquery

How can i add and remove dynamically component through jquery?

I want on click Add on my page add one row and then in that row there will be new text box 
and same in delete on click Delete button on my page selected checkbox rows must ve deleted with its components like text box

how would i do with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Click here`](http://jsfiddle.net/DuXgq/) to view demo

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent = document.getElementById('id');
var next = $.create("<div></div>");
 $.append(parent);
```

for removing `$('#myelement').remove('id')`

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>m2z</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        function addNew() {             
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById('mainContainer');               
            var newDiv = document.createElement('div');             
            var newText = document.createElement('input');
            newText.type = "input";
            var newDelButton = document.createElement('input');
            newDelButton.type = "button";
            newDelButton.value = "Delete";
            newDiv.appendChild(newText);                
            newDiv.appendChild(newDelButton);               
            mainContainer.appendChild(newDiv);              
            newDelButton.onclick = function() {
                    mainContainer.removeChild(newDiv);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head> 
<body >
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div><input type="text" ><input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addNew()"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```